# I am using dreamweaver cs6 to create a Single Page App and it is telling me that there is a syntax error

Tags: syntax

I am using dreamweaver cs6 to create a Single Page App and it is telling me that There is a syntax error even though I am following the book verbatim. everything worked fine until I added the 4 following lines    chat_extend_time    : 1000, 
                       chat_retract_time   : 300, 
                       chat_extend_height  : 450, 
                       chat_retract_height : 15

```
var
configMap = {
   main_html : String()
     + '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-main">'
     + '<div class="spa-shell-main-nav"></div>'
     + '<div class="spa-shell-main-content"></div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-foot"></div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-chat"></div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-modal"></div>'

    chat_extend_time    : 1000, 
    chat_retract_time   : 300, 
    chat_extend_height  : 450, 
    chat_retract_height : 15        
  },
```

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
var
configMap = {
   main_html : String()
     + '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>'
      + '<div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-main">'
     + '<div class="spa-shell-main-nav"></div>'
     + '<div class="spa-shell-main-content"></div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-foot"></div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-chat"></div>'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-modal"></div>', <-- comma needed here
    chat_extend_time    : 1000, 
    chat_retract_time   : 300, 
    chat_extend_height  : 450, 
    chat_retract_height : 15        
  },
```

You're making a class with properties, and they all need to be separated by commas.

Comment: thanks a lot Paul. I'm new to programming thank you. This site is the best. I just posted an answer wow

Comment: Thanks A lot Paul. It now works. This site is amazing. I just posted this question